# LINQ Include Extension - Drill Down

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am able to use the strongly typed LINQ Extension : **.Include**

```
result = (from A in context.Transactions.Include(_ => _.TransactionDetails)
          where A.TransactionId == transactionId
          select A).SingleOrDefault();
```

However I cannot go further within **TransactionDetails**. My **TransactionDetails** also have a navigation named **User** however I don't know how to put it. The available options I have inside **TransactiomDetails** are the regular extensions for Collections (e.g First ; FirstOrDefault,etc).

I was able to do it using the regular string method (That I want to avoid) :

```
result = (from A in context.Transactions.Include(_ => _.TransactionDetails)
                                        .Include("TransactionDetails.User")
          where A.TransactionId == transactionId
          select A).SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do something like this and it'll work:


var query = dataContext.OrderItems.Include("Product").Include("Product.OrderItemTypes").ToList();

From now on you have access to Product and through Product to OrderItemTypes also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
result = context.Transactions
                .Where(t => t.TransactionId == transactionId)
                .Include(t => t.TransactionDetails.Select(u => u.User))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So inside a LINQ Query as I have it's not possible ?

Comment: Maybe it's possible but this is the proper way.That will include your TransactionDetails and User

Comment: My question is due to some SQL Generation analysis I did in the past, and usually accessing the context directly using extensions EF produces a higher number of queries to get the same data.

Comment: @hugohilario If the program using this query ends up taking longer than is acceptable for your requirements then consider evaluating its query plan, and compare its execution speed to a custom query.  If you can dramatically improve performance consider refactoring the code so that this is a stored procedure that you call, or simply avoid using EF for that one query, if you have shown it fails to translate it effectively.  Note that, by and large, the SQL translations often result in much larger and messier SQL code, but the DB's query compiler can optimize it down to something equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @Servy I agree. Meanwhile I checked the generated SQL of both options and apparently now (E.F 6) generates the same SQL, which is good. Thanks a lot